# Parse XML From Wikipedia

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, nsmutablestring

I'm using `NSXmlParser` and trying to parse this XML file:

```
<api>
<query>
<normalized>
<n from="new york" to="New york"/>
</normalized>
<redirects>
<r from="New york" to="New York"/>
</redirects>
<pages>
<page pageid="8210131" ns="0" title="New York">
<extract xml:space="preserve">&lt;p>&lt;b>New York&lt; ...
```

Basically this file is pretty long but I am trying to copy only the `<extract>` element.

I have done it by several way with `NSMutableString` with this code:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    CrrentString = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    [CrrentString appendString:string];
    NSLog(@"%@",CrrentString);
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
   didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
     attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentKey = nil;

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"extract"]) {
        CrrentString = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"extract"];
        return;
    }
}
```

But in the end, this gives me only `>` inside the `NSMutableString` (`CrrentString`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line makes the issue:

```
CrrentString = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Each time when the found character method works it overwrites the previous `CrrentString`. That's why you are getting the last found character only.

So change it like:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *temp= (NSString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    [CrrentString appendString:temp];
    NSLog(@"%@",CrrentString);
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    CrrentString = nil;

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"extract"])
    {
        CrrentString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}
```

Hope it'll help.